# Identify values in multiple columns, and populate a new column based on the result

Tags: r

I only have some basic R experience. I am working with a large dataset of medical data. There are 15 columns with procedure codes (PR#), and an additional 15 corresponding columns for the time of those procedures (PRDAYS#), with each row being one patient. What I would like to do is go through the 15 columns of procedures, and identify 6 specific codes that I have. I want to generate a new binary variable, for each specific patient, if they have at least one of the 6 codes within any of the 15 PR# columns, then the new variable is 0. I then want to generate a second variable that takes the corresponding procedure time of that variable. For example, let's say the code I am interested in is S55. A patient with a PR1 of S55, and PRDAYS1 of 2 would have a new variable PR_bin of 1, and PR_time of 2. A patient without any S55 in their PR numbers would result in PR_bin of 0, and PR_time of NA.

I hope that makes sense! Definitely new to stackoverflow.

Thank you!

Edit: some sample code. For simplicity, I only included 3 procedures (with 3 times). Let's say I'm interested in S55 and S25. If both exist (row 2), I want the shorter time of the two listed in PR_time. If neither, PR_time should be NA.

```
       PR1 PR2 PR3 PRDAYS1 PRDAYS2 PRDAYS3 PR_bin PR_time
    1  S55 S03 S01    1       2       1      1      1
    2  S23 S55 S25    1       2       1      1      1 
    3  S02 S03 S05    1       8       2      0      NA
    4  S55 S02 S05    6       5       3      1      6      
    5  S25 S52 S22    3       7       2      1      3
```

Comment: It sounds like either `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when` will help you here but if you show what some of your data looks like can help more

Comment: I added some sample code to the bottom of my original post!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
# creating a version of your data
PR1 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR2 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR3 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR4 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR5 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR6 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR7 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR8 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR9 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR10 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR11 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR12 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR13 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR14 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PR15 = paste0("S", round(runif(length(PR),40,80)))
PatientID = paste0("PID", seq(1,length(PR1),1))
PRDAYS1 = round(runif(length(PR),1,10))

# turn all of the arrays into a data frame 
data <- data.frame(PatientID, PR1, PR2, PR3, PR4, PR5,
                   PR6, PR7, PR8, PR9, PR10, PR11, PR12,
                   PR13, PR14, PR15, PRDAYS1, stringsAsFactors = F)

# your 6 procedure codes you are looking for
Procedures.of.interest = c("S55", "S50", "S42", "S60", "S59", "S52")

# make sure you have tidyverse installed - if you havent install.packages("tidyverse")
require(tidyverse)

# search all of the columns for your procedures 
data <- data %>% group_by(PatientID) %>%
  mutate(PR_bin = T %in% (Procedures.of.interest %in% c(PR1, PR2, PR3, PR4, PR5,
                                               PR6, PR7, PR8, PR9, PR10, PR11, PR12,
                                               PR13, PR14, PR15)))

# convert the trues to 1 and falses to 0
data$PR_bin <- ifelse(data$PR_bin == T, 1, 0)

# add the PR days if PR_bin was 1 otherwise add NA
data$PR_time <- ifelse(data$PR_bin == 1, data$PRDAYS1, NA)

# view the new data 
View(data)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This definitely helps, but do you know how I could handle it given the separate times for each procedure? (There are PR1 through PR15, but also the corresponding PRDAYS1 through PRDAYS15 as well)

Comment: A procedure code could potentially appear twice if the patient has the same procedure a second time during the same admission.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume the columns are always in the same, logical, order, we can do it shorter:

```
interest <- c('S25', 'S55')
data$PR_time <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
  min(ifelse(data[i,1:3] %in% interest,
             unlist(data[i,4:6]),
             999))
})
data$PR_time[data$PR_time==999] <- NA
data$PR_bin <- !is.na(data$PR_time)
# Or to set to 0/1:
data$PR_bin <- ifelse(!is.na(data$PR_time), 1, 0)
```

This is to solve for your example, but you can easily adjust for more columns.

The `sapply`-function looks scary, but if you work more with R it turns out to be very useful. It applies a function over different values, in this case a self-written function, for each of the rows. The result is like a for-loop, but it doesn't need to happen sequentially.

The real work is done by the `ifelse` to match the operation-durations with the condition: is the operation of interest to us. So for the first row, we look which values are of interest, which gives us `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`. For the `TRUE`, we take a value from the next argument, for the `FALSE`s we look at the argument after that. And finally we combine, so we get `1, 999, 999`. The minimum of these is 1, so that's what we store.

The endresult is a list of shortest operations, or 999 if there is none.

Finally, we clean it up: set values of 999 to `NA`, and now it's easy to set PR_bin

Comment: This worked perfectly and completely took care of it. Thank you!